# Is "in full length" the same as "fully" here?

Tags: phrases

> I have no time to unfold my own view on this in full length.
>   (self-made)

Is this “in full length” the same as “fully”? So it is correct to use it here?

Answer (score 1):

> I have no time to unfold my own view on this in full length.

The phrase, *in full length*,  is easily understood in your sentence but as an adjective, *full-length*, is usually reserved for objects which are visible, such as: *A full-length mirror*; *a full-length portrait*; *a full-length dress* etc. Sometimes it means a standard measure or quantity as in *a full-length movie/film*. Note the hyphen and how it is usually positioned in front of the noun.

I do however, find the whole sentence to be slightly awkward and unnecessarily *lengthy*.
Moreover, *to unfold a view* is not idiomatic. More suitable verbs with [*view*](http://www.ozdic.com/collocation-dictionary/view) in this context would be:

- express
- air
- convey
- expound
- make known
- present
- put forward

Therefore, if I had to write that sentence in a formal way,  I might say:

> I have no time to expound/present my view **at length**

Comment: how is it an *adjectival phrase*? What noun does it modify?

Comment: @virmaior, *view* is the noun, meaning *opinion*; a point of view, or a theory.

Comment: I will edit my answer, @virmaior made a valid observation

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for others, but I would not say *in full length*.

I would either say *in full* or *fully* with both being adverbial uses.

My basic reason is that *views* do not normally have lengths, do they?